# Expanding expression trees in sympy, keeping certain binomials together

Tags: python, sympy

I am manipulating multivariate polynomials in sympy that are all expressed as sums of products of terms of the form (x_i + y_j), where the i and j are indices, and I want to keep it that way, i.e. express everything in terms of sums of one x symbol and one y symbol.

For example, I want

```
(y_{1} + z_{2})*((0 + 1)*(y_{3} + z_{2}) + y_{1} + z_{1} + 0 + 0)
```

to become

```
(y_{1} + z_{2})*(y_{3} + z_{2}) + (y_{1} + z_{2})*(y_{1} + z_{1})
```

Comment: Maybe you could `collect` on the common factor. The code provided doesn't produce any expression (the function is not called) so I'm not sure if that would work in this case.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I can post the complete code and command line that produce the example, but it's 195 lines of code. I'm new to this site, I'm not sure if that's too much to post.

Comment: Ideally you would remove all of the extraneous details and distil this down to a simple example with just a few symbols. No need to show your original code but it's much better to show something complete that can actually be run.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin I ended up posting my whole script, getting an example like this requires calling the base function many times, which is done by an outer function, so I just posted the whole thing.

Comment: You've posted so much code I don't even know which part of it you are referring to. I am pretty sure that it only takes a few lines of code to make an expression that can demonstrate what you are trying to do. Please take the time to do that. Note that from my perspective the purpose of this site is to answer questions in general terms so that future readers can get some benefit from the answer. I'm not interested in debugging your problem in particular but in creating a curated set of useful Q+A. The more extraneous detail there is the less useful this question will be to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you can do is replace binomials that fit the pattern with dummy and expand. The problem is that you will have some dangling terms to group together. If you always have two, then it's easy. If you have more it will require more work and a good definition of which subindexed `x` should go with which `y` (or whatever letters you want paired up).

So let's start with your unevaluated expression which we will call `u`

Get the free symbols (assuming there are only `x` and `y` of interest):

```
>>> free = u.free_symbols
```

Replace existing binomials with a unique dummy variable

```
>>> reps = {}
>>> u.replace(lambda x:x.is_Add and len(x.args) == 2 and all(
...              i in free for i in x.args),
...          lambda x: reps.setdefault(x, Dummy()))
_Dummy_45*(_Dummy_47*(0 + 1) + y1 + z1)
```

Now expand

```
>>> expand(_)
_Dummy_45*_Dummy_47 + _Dummy_45*y1 + _Dummy_45*z1
```

and collect products of dummy symbols together

```
>>> _.replace(lambda x:x.is_Mul and len(x.args) == 2 and all(
...              i in reps.values() for i in x.args),
...    lambda x: reps.setdefault(x, Dummy())))
_Dummy_45*y1 + _Dummy_45*z1 + _Dummy_51
```

Collect on dummy symbols to get binomials to appear that were previously dangling

```
>>> collect(_, reps.values())
_Dummy_45*(y1 + z1) + _Dummy_51
```

Now replace Dummy symbols with their values (which are the keys in reps so we have to invert that dictionary):

```
>>> _.xreplace({v:k for k,v in reps.items()})
_Dummy_45*_Dummy_47 + (y1 + z1)*(y1 + z2)
```

Do it again

```
>>> _.xreplace({v:k for k,v in reps.items()})
(y1 + z1)*(y1 + z2) + (y1 + z2)*(y3 + z2)
```

Posting specific expressions that you would like to see re-arranged in some way would help to focus a more robust solution, but these techniques can get you started. Here, too, is a function that pairs up free symbols in an Add and replaces them with Dummy symbols.

```
def collect_pairs(e, X, Y):
    free = e.free_symbols
    xvars, yvars = [[i for i in free if i.name.startswith(j)] for j in (X, Y)]
    reps = {}
    def do(e):
        if not e.is_Add: return e
        x, cy = sift(e.args, lambda x: x in xvars, binary=True)
        y, c = sift(cy, lambda x: x in yvars, binary=True)
        if x and len(x) != len(y): return e
        args = []
        for i,j in zip(ordered(x), ordered(y)):
            args.append(reps.setdefault(i+j, Dummy()))
        return Add(*(c + args))
    # hmmm...this destroys the reps and returns {}
    #return {v:k for k,v in reps.items()}, bottom_up(e, do)
    return reps, bottom_up(e, do)


>>> e1
(y1 + z2)*(y1 + y3 + z1 + z2)
>>> r, e = collect_pairs(e1,'y','z')
>>> expand(e).xreplace({v:k for k,v in r.items()})
(y1 + z1)*(y1 + z2) + (y1 + z2)*(y3 + z2)
```

This works with the fully expanded `e1` if you factor it first:

```
>>> e2 = factor(expand(e1)); e2
(y1 + z2)*(y1 + y3 + z1 + z2)
>>> r, e = collect_pairs(e2, 'y', 'z')
>>> expand(e).xreplace({v:k for k,v in r.items()})
(y1 + z1)*(y1 + z2) + (y1 + z2)*(y3 + z2)
```

Looking at the code you originally posted, I would suggest keeping the binomials together and only replace them at the end, like this:

```
...
def single_variable_diff(perm_dict,k,m):
    ret_dict = {}
    for perm,val in perm_dict.items():
        if len(perm)<k:
            ret_dict[perm] = Add(ret_dict.get(perm,0), reps.setdefault(U(var2[k],var3[m]), Dummy())*val,evaluate=False)
        else:
            ret_dict[perm] = Add(ret_dict.get(perm,0), reps.setdefault(U(var2[perm[k-1]],var3[m]), Dummy())*val,evaluate=False)
...

reps = {}
U = lambda x,y: UnevaluatedExpr(Add(*ordered((x,y))))
ireps = lambda: {v:k for k,v in reps.items()}

perms=[]
curperm = []

...

coeff_perms.sort(key=lambda x: (inv(x),*x))

def touch(e):
    from sympy.core.traversal import bottom_up
    def do(e):
        return e if not e.args else e.func(*e.args)
    return bottom_up(e, do)

undo = ireps()
for perm in coeff_perms:
    val = touch(coeff_dict[perm]).expand().xreplace(undo))
    print(f"{str(perm):>{width}} {str(val)}")
```

(3, 4, 1, 2) will be given in terms of binomial products, but some elements will not -- they are just sums of binomials. In ordered to keep them together, you can create them as UnevaluatedExpr, e.g. the `U` lambda that is defined. I am guessing you don't have to use `evaluated=False` and will, then, not need the `touch` function.

Comment: So it does matter which y's are paired with which z's. In my example, in the unevaluated tree the (y_{3}+z_{2}) is separately grouped, so I would want it to distribute that and then the (y_{1}+z_{1}) separately. Does this do that in general, or does it pick arbitrary y's and z's to pair?

Comment: The code you deleted does matter in that sense; it's possible to tell which y's pair with which z's from the code, because the two basic operations are multiplying by (yi+zj) and adding two expressions. I admit the full script probably wasn't helpful.

Comment: The code you posted does not use variable `var` and generates an index error when you try to run it. Nonetheless, I suggest a modification to keep track of the binomials until after the expansion in the answer I gave.

Comment: That's odd because I directly pasted the script I'm using. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: I ran it interpretively with this for-loop: `for s in '1 4 3 2 - 1 4 3 2'.split():`

Comment: Ah, I think index 0 in argv is the script name. That could be it if that's all you changed.

Comment: Yes, that's why I started with the first `s` as `1`. I also changed the `n` at the outset to 4 -- changing it back to 100 allowed the program to run (apolgies!). `xreplace` is needed when looking at the final values. I will update the answer.

Comment: Thanks I'll have to try the update, it's slow going though since this is my hobby and not my day job. Just going to ask in case you tested, does everything come out with nonnegative coefficients when you do this? That's the goal. I conjecture there's exact cancellation without having to rearrange the binomials. If not I would have to resort to an answer to this (so far unanswered) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404782/algorithm-for-expressing-a-homogeneous-polynomial-with-integer-coefficients-nonn).

Comment: I implemented it. It does indeed keep the y's and z's together and expands everything with respect to that, but (3, 4, 1, 2) doesn't split up like I had hoped. Not sure why not.

Comment: When I look at that value I don't see how you want it to group -- there appear to be multiple ways.  `perm=(3,4,1,2); val = touch(coeff_dict[perm]).expand().xreplace(undo); r,e=cse(val); e->[x0*x1 - x0*x3 + x1*x2 + x3*(x0 + x2) - (x0 - x1 - x3 + (y_{4} + z_{2}))*(y_{4} + z_{3})]` and each of those `xi` are a simple binomial.

Comment: There are usually multiple ways, if you have all factors in common but one you can exchange the z values of the remaining factors, but in the unevaluated expressions I noticed you didn't have to do that in order for it to cancel, you just had to pull out, in this case, y1 + z1 to cancel, which was already grouped together on some iteration of single_variable_diff. If I made my own expression tree system I could probably work it out, which I used to do in the old days (just used built in Java to code my own polynomial classes, over a decade ago) but I was hoping to. (cont.)

Comment: It's also entirely possible that I'm misinterpreting the expression trees and the cancellation actually doesn't happen with the original grouping, it's just sympy being clever (when I ran this on my old computer, with an older version of everything, I don't remember seeing any minus signs in the result, so either an older version of sympy was doing a great job or I wasn't looking closely enough). Anyway you've probably done all you can do. I'll leave this unaccepted for awhile in case someone else wants to try, but I'll probably accept it later. Thanks.